# intersection and union of two unsorted arrays

Tags: c, arrays

This code is meant to find intersection and union of two unsorted arrays which may contain duplicates.

The union works fine, but when trying to access intersection array memory, I get garbage results.

I can't find out where the problem is, tried to debug it but it didn't help me much either.

note: `remember[]` is an array of flags that saves indices of intersection elements in two arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n1,n2,j;
    int user1[20];
    int unionSize;
    int intersectionArraySize;
    printf("enter array1 size::\n");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    printf("array1: ");
    for(i=0; i<n1; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&user1[i]);
        if (i>0) if(user1[i]==user1[i-1])  user1[i-1]=user1[i];

    }
    int user2[20];
    printf("enter array2 size::\n");
    scanf("%d",&n2);
    for(i=0; i<n2; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&user2[i]);
        if (i>0) if(user2[i]==user2[i-1])  user2[i-1]=user2[i];


    }

    int unionArray[20];
    int remember[20]= {0}; // save index of common elements btn 2 arrays
    int intersectionArray[20]={0};
    intersectionArraySize=0;
    unionSize=n1;
    int index=0;

    for(i=0; i<n1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n2; j++)
        {
            if (user1[i]==user2[j])
            {
                remember[j]=1;
                intersectionArray[index]==user1[i];
                intersectionArraySize++;
                index++;
            }
            else unionArray[i]=user1[i];
        }

    }
    for(i=0; i<n2; i++)
    {
        if(remember[i]!=1)
        {
            unionArray[n1]=user2[i];
            n1++;
            unionSize++;
        }
    }

    printf("Union: ");
    for (i=0; i<unionSize; i++)
    {
        if(i==unionSize-1) printf("%d\n",unionArray[i]);
        else printf("%d ,",unionArray[i]);
    }
    printf("intersection: ");
    for (i=0; i<intersectionArraySize; i++)
    {
        if(i==intersectionArraySize-1) printf("%d\n",intersectionArray[i]);
        else printf("%d ,",intersectionArray[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by garbage results?

Comment: You could use a function for the input, passing the arrays in.  Did you consider sorting the arrays before operating on them?  Union is simply the combination of the two arrays unless your union has to be a set (no repeats).  If you have six 1s in one array and four 1s in the other, presumably the intersection contains four 1s.  Can you mangle the arrays while processing them?

Comment: Just a coding tip: use `if (a && b)` instead of `if (a) if (b)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I couldn't think of a better solution .... do you mean for example to iterate through intersection array and delete duplicates?

Comment: @Milack27 at which part did I write if(a)if(b)?

Comment: Line 16: `if (i>0) if(user1[i]==user1[i-1])  user1[i-1]=user1[i];`

Comment: @Milack27 thanks for your help milack!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
intersectionArray[index]==user1[i];
```

It should be:

```
intersectionArray[index]=user1[i];
```

General comments on your code:

It's pretty bad designed. For instance, unless you have a very good reason, do not calculate both at the same time. Have one block that does intersection and only that. Same for union.

You declare the arrays with a fixed size, which is a bit weird since you ask for the sizes. Not a very big deal, but be aware of dangers if you enter a size over 20.

What's worse is that `unionArray` has a size of 20. It should be 40.

`index` and `intersectionArraySize` is practically the same variable. Get rid of one.

This looks messy:

```
for (i=0; i<unionSize; i++) {
        if(i==unionSize-1) printf("%d\n",unionArray[i]);
        else printf("%d ,",unionArray[i]);
    }
```

Do like this:

```
for (i=0; i<unionSize-2; i++) {
        printf("%d ,",unionArray[i]);
    }
    printf("%d\n", unionArray[unionSize-1]);
```

Also not a very big deal, but why do a conditional check on every single element when you know that it is the last that should be treated specially?

Comment: You mean `for (i=0; i<unionSize-1; i++)`? I think the element `i = unionSize - 2` is being skipped.

Comment: @klutt  what do you recommend to improve my coding design and stuff like that?

Comment: Yes I do recommend improving the design. Try making code modular. I'd make a function that calculates the intersection. Search for "modular" and "test driven development". I'm not 100% convinced that test driven development is always a good thing, but I know for certain that you should make your code testable. Before you write ANY function, you should consider how you might write an automated test for it. If you don't know how, then you're not ready to write the code.